# How should I determine the explicit type returned by a query to a GraphQL interface type?

Tags: interface, graphql

Say we have this GraphQL schema that uses inheritance:

```
Query {
  maintenanceEvents: [MaintenanceEvent]!
}

interface MaintenaceEvent {
  time: DateTime
}

type OilChange implements MaintenanceEvent {
  time: DateTime
  oilType: OilType
}

type TireRotation implements MaintenanceEvent {
  time: DateTime
  pattern: RotationPattern
}

... more types
```

And say the client will display a summary of the types of events that occurred on a timeline. The problem is that (as far as I can tell) there is no straightforward way for the client to determine the types of each event in the array it receives from the server.

Some options I have come up with:

1. Add a "type" field to the interface and to each type that implements it.

   This looks like this:

   ```
   enum MaintenanceEventType {
     OIL_CHANGE
     TIRE_ROTATION
     ... more types
   }

   interface MaintenanceEvent {
     time: DateTime
     type: MaintenanceEventType
   }

   type OilChange implements MaintenanceEvent {
     time: DateTime
     type: MaintenanceEventType
     oilType: OilType
   }

   ...etc.
   ```

   This is the best option I have come up with, but there there are things about it I don't like. There are two lists of maintenance event types to keep in sync: the enum, and the set of interfaces. Also, it seems redundant to send a field that is always the same for a given type.
2. Determine the type in the front-end based on which fields are present.

   This is not a good option. It is error-prone and the logic to determine which type is which will change if fields are added to the types. Also, it cannot handle types that implement the interface but do not have additional fields.

Is there an established pattern for this, or a part of the GraphQL specification that handles this? Is this not a good application of GraphQL interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `__typename` field. From the [spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Type-Name-Introspection):

> GraphQL supports type name introspection at any point within a query by the meta‐field __typename: String! when querying against any Object, Interface, or Union. It returns the name of the object type currently being queried.
>
> This is most often used when querying against Interface or Union types to identify which actual type of the possible types has been returned.
>
> This field is implicit and does not appear in the fields list in any defined type.

Your query would look something like:

```
query {
  maintenanceEvents {
    __typename
    time
    ... on OilChange {
      oilType
    }
    ... on TireRotation {
      pattern
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if you use Apollo Client, the `__typename` field will automatically be added to your queries -- there's no need to explicitly add it yourself in that case.